# Showing content associated with node reference in a view

Tags: views, nodes

I have created a "Node Reference Field" in a content type named "TV Shows" . ( And it is  referring to another Content Type "Episodes")

I created a view which takes the NID of "TV shows" from Contextual filters . How to  display all the fields of related "Episodes" to that "TV show ."

cheers :)

Comment: Have you tried to add relation? Right top corner? Sorry for not answering, but I don't have a project with node reference at hand, I'm using entityreference these days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have a single node (type TV Show) with several related nodes of type Episodes, each Episode node describing an episode of the particular TV show.

If this is correct, this is a common error. Your node reference field should be on the Episode type, and should refer to the TV Show type.

Then a simple view of Episodes with a contextual filter on Node ID will give you what you want. Just make sure the reference goes in the correct direction.